# How to use bunnycdn laravel module?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I found BunnyCDN Module on GitHub, I want to use the module for my laravel application. Anyone, please tell me how can I do that?

Github Link: https://github.com/PlatformCommunity/flysystem-bunnycdn

Thank you.

Comment: Follow the installation and usage instructions in that package... Is there more to this question? Did you try something and get an error? Also, is this Laravel 4 or Laravel 5? You have it tagged as both, but it's one or the other.

Comment: I purchased  Laravel 5 application from codecanyon 

i run this command on ssh:"" composer require platformcommunity/flysystem-bunnycdn ""

but don't understand if installed or not.

Comment: Read thes blog. Full guide for bunny cdn - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268181/how-to-use-bunnycdn-laravel-module